# Autofocus does not work in form inside a partial view using MVC3 Razor

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, autofocus

I am using MVC 3 Razor and I have a simple form in a PartialView [I am showing this as a popup window]. Some of the features are not working properly in PartialView. For example the autofocus attribute.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Code, new { style = "width:50px", maxlength = 4, autofocus = "" })
```

I have tried setting the focus through jQuery script but that doesn't work either.

```
$('#Code').focus();
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to import some scripts in my partial view for this to work?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Update:

I found the problem... I was loading the window and then showing it after a delay of 700ms. I commented out the setTimeout line and it worked. It must be that the focus worked when form loaded but when I actually did the "open()" it lost focus again.

Previous Code

```
function openWindow(url, title) {
  var window = $("#Window").data("tWindow");
  window.ajaxRequest(url);
  window.title(title);
  setTimeout(showWindow, 700);
}

function showWindow() {
  var window = $("#Window").data("tWindow");
  window.open().center();
}
```

New Code

```
function openWindow(url, title) {
  var window = $("#Window").data("tWindow");
  window.ajaxRequest(url);
  window.title(title).open().center();;
//setTimeout(showWindow, 700);
}
```

Thanks everyone for your replies. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Is you JS in your pop-up window? Is it an iFrame or inline?

Comment: I actually do not have any script apart from $('#Code').focus(); and yes I am having this script in the PartialView itself.. I am using Telerik's window and loading the content from a Partial View.

Comment: check if your js is loading use fiddler or firebug

Comment: I have tried $('#Code').focus() from firebug too. It doesn't work. It doesn't show any error, just returns the input object.

Comment: please check the JS library that you are loading on the pop-up

Comment: I need to see your code. Are you using the `LoadContentFrom()` method or are you simply rendering a `@Html.Partial("view")` in the `Content()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function openWindow(url, title) {
  var window = $("#Window").data("tWindow");
  window.ajaxRequest(url);
  window.title(title).open().center();
  //call after the content has been loaded from the Ajax request
  document.getElementById('Code').focus();
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried your code, but it says focus() is undefined.

Comment: I have double checked all the JS files. 
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I need to see your code. Are you using the `LoadContentFrom()` method or are you simply rendering a `@Html.Partial("view")` in the `Content()` method?

Comment: Very strange. Next time I would recommend using the built in events found here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/window/clientsideevents You could have called the `onActivate` event and then set the focus.